# angular $scope in selector

Tags: jquery, angularjs, api, asp.net-web-api

everybody.
I am new to AngularJS and find it very interesting, but I am a bit unclear about the following situation.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
$('#light-pagination').pagination({
    items: count,
    itemsOnPage: 10,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
        ajaxHelper(AccountingObjectUri + '?$skip=' + (pageNumber * 10 - 10) + "&$top=10", 'GET').done(function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            $scope.AccountingObject = data; //not working
        });
    }
});
```

}

i can't assign $scope.AccountingObject = data;is there anyway I can assign the return data to the $scope?

Comment: I'm not angular guru but i think angular has no way to know you change `$scope.AccountingObject`  value. You should update DOM inside a directive, not a controller. Calling `$scope.$apply()` should work but im' quite sure this isn't really the way to go.

Comment: Does `console.log(data);` happen? If yes then the reason you can't see data in your view is that you're bypassing the angular part of your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPageClick` is occurring outside of the usual angular lifecycle. You need to call `$scope.$apply()` after assigning data to tell angular to update the view.

```
.done(function(data) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
     $scope.AccountingObject = data;
  });
});
```

Within angular a general rule is no direct DOM manipulation within a controller, the preferred method is to use a directive with a link function that modifies the DOM (i.e. calling `pagination()`).

Comment: Even more so angular directives give you a hook into the DOM that they represent with the `elem/element` object in the link function. It will either be a full jQuery object or a jQLite object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.$evalAsync`.

```
                $scope.$evalAsync(function() {                    

                    $scope.AccountingObject = data;

                });
```

Ideally you should update the DOM inside a directive an not in a controller.

Comment: i tried it. but is not working. the $scope.AccountingObject need assign inner controller. is there anyway I can assign the return data using a directive.